# Laravel edit route is not working..404 not found error

Tags: laravel, routes

Hi guys i have button where i am redirecting to edit page..but i am getting 404 Not found

Here is my button link:

```
->addColumn('edit_header_action', function ($row) {
            return '<a href="' . route('eqtype-editor.editRulesStep', $row->id) . '" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;margin-top:20px;" class="btn btn-danger">Edit Rules Step 1</a>';
        })
```

Here is my function:

```
public function editRulesStep($id)
{
    $qtype_editor = Qtype_editor::findOrFail($id);

    $qtype_json = $qtype_editor->qtype_json;

    $title = 'Set Question Conditions';

    return view('eqtype_editor.edit_rules_step_1', compact('qtype_editor', 'qtype_json', 'title'));
}
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('/eqtype-editor/{eqtype-editor}/editRulesStep', 'QtypeEditorController@editRulesStep')->name('eqtype-editor.editRulesStep');
```

And when i click on  my button my url is showing like this:

```
xxx.local/eqtype-editor/editRulesStep/1
```

and page is showing 404 Not Found:

Can anyone help me where i did mistake.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/eqtype-editor/{eqtype-editor}` here `eqtype-editor}` != `$id` make `Route::get('/eqtype-editor/{id}/editRulesStep')`  here `{id}` as parameter so in controller you can accept it `$id`

Comment: Done working..thank you.